# Using cython_gsl for integration (plus addressing numpy.array to cython)

Tags: c, arrays, numpy, cython, gsl

I want to improve the speed of my code, so I am transferring my original Python code to Cython. The bottleneck of the code is the integration part I was doing with `scipy.integral.quad` an then concatenating bunch of `numpy.array` and `sum` over each row of a 2D array. So I am trying to re-write the classes I am using in Cython.

My class is as following:

```
import numpy as np
import cosmology
from cython_gsl cimport *

ctypedef double * double_ptr
ctypedef void * void_ptr


cdef class Cosmology(object):
    cdef double omega_c
    def __init__(self, double omega_m=0.3, double omega_lam=0.7):
        # no quintessence, no radiation in this universe!
        self.omega_m = omega_m
        self.omega_lam = omega_lam
        self.omega_c = (1. - omega_m - omega_lam)

    cdef double a(self, double z):
        return 1./(1+z)

    cdef double E(self, double a):
        return (self.omega_m*a**(-3) + self.omega_c*a**(-2) + self.omega_lam)**0.5

    cdef double __angKernel(self, double x, void * params) nogil:
        cdef double alpha, f
        alpha = (<double_ptr> params)[0]
        f=self.E(alpha*x**-1)**-1
        return f

    cdef double Da(self, int size, double *z, double z_ref=0):
        cdef gsl_integration_workspace *w
        cdef double result, error, expected, alpha
        w = gsl_integration_workspace_alloc (1000)
        cdef gsl_function F
        if size>1:
           da = np.zeros(size)
           for i in range(size):
               da[i] = self.Da(1, &z[i], z_ref)
           return da
        else:
           if z[0] < 0:
                    raise ValueError("Redshift z must not be negative")
           if z[0] < z_ref:
                    raise ValueError("Redshift z must not be smaller than the reference redshift")

           expected = -4.0
           alpha = 1

           F.function = &self.__angKernel
           F.params = &alpha

           gsl_integration_qags (&F, z_ref+1, z[0]+1, 0, 1e-7, 1000, w, &result, &error)
           d=result
           rk = (abs(self.omega_c))**0.5
           if (rk*d > 0.01):
              if self.omega_c > 0:
                 d = sinh(rk*d)/rk
              if self.omega_c < 0:
                 d = sin(rk*d)/rk
           return d/(1+z[0])


cdef class halo_positions(object):
    cdef double *x 
    cdef double *y 
    def __init__(self, double[:] positions):
        self.x = &positions[0]
        self.y = &positions[1]
```

I am trying to use `cython_gsl` for integration and after I tried to implement it my integrand and building the `cnfw_model.pyx` code. I got this error message:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
                    raise ValueError("Redshift z must not be smaller than the reference redshift")

           expected = -4.0
           alpha = 1

           F.function = &self.__angKernel
                       ^
------------------------------------------------------------

cnfw_model.pyx:102:24: Cannot assign type 'double (*)(Cosmology, double, void *) nogil' to 'double (*)(double, void *) nogil'

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
    cdef double __angKernel(self, double x, void * params) nogil:
        cdef double alpha, f
        alpha = (<double_ptr> params)[0]
        """Integration kernel for angular diameter distance computation.
        """
        f=self.E(alpha*x**-1)**-1
               ^
------------------------------------------------------------

cnfw_model.pyx:73:16: Calling gil-requiring function not allowed without gil
```

I don't know how `function F` should be defined to avoid this problem.

**second**: in `class halo_positions`, I want to change it in order to get a 2xN dimension array and divide it to two 1xN dimension array and assign it to `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be similar to a problem that also happens in C++ (I don't code in python, but the issue seems to be the same). You can't convert member functions to global functions. Remember that gsl_function is the following c_struct

```
struct gsl_function_struct 
{
   double (* function) (double x, void * params);
   void * params;
};

typedef struct gsl_function_struct gsl_function ;
```

And you can see that the gsl.function is a pointer to a global function (member functions have an extra parameter that holds the pointer "this").

The github for cython_gsl has [an example](https://github.com/twiecki/CythonGSL/blob/master/examples/integrate.pyx) where integration is done on a global function.

```
from cython_gsl cimport *

ctypedef double * double_ptr
ctypedef void * void_ptr

cdef double normal(double x, void * params) nogil:
  cdef double mu = (<double_ptr> params)[0]
  cdef double sigma = (<double_ptr> params)[1]

  return gsl_ran_gaussian_pdf(x - mu, sigma)

def cdf_numerical(double x, double mu, double sigma):
  cdef double alpha, result, error, expected
  cdef gsl_integration_workspace * W
  W = gsl_integration_workspace_alloc(1000)
  cdef gsl_function F
  cdef double params[1]
  cdef size_t neval

  params[0] = mu
  params[1] = sigma

  F.function = &normal
  F.params = params

  gsl_integration_qag(&F, -10, x, 1e-2, 1e-2, 1000, GSL_INTEG_GAUSS15, W, &result, &error)
  gsl_integration_workspace_free(W)

  return result
```

One way to solve this is to create a global function that wraps the member function. In this case, you will need to send the class pointer in the void parameter.